# Limit login attempts in Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I have Laravel 5.7 project with custom login. How can I let Laravel accept three login attempts after that redirect for page waiting to 2 or 3 min, etc?

```
public function loginPost(LoginRequest $request)
{
    if (Auth::attempt(array('user_name' => $request->user_name, 'password' => $request->user_pass)))
    {
        if(Auth::check())
            return redirect('/');
        else
            return back();
    }
    else
    {
        return "login faled call administrator";
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out the ThrottlesLogin trait and the default scaffolding included with Laravel.

Comment: can you Write the code

Comment: Can you look at the code?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> you can do it in two way

1. add the Laravel built-in  `throttle middleware` in route for example

   ```
    Route::post("/user/login","LoginController@login")->middleware("throttle:10,2");
   ```

> it will allow 10 requests per 2 minute

2. Use the Built-in `Trait ThrottlesLogins`

first, add `ThrottlesLogins trait` in the loginController and this line in the login method

```
if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
    $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);
    return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
}

if(attempt()) {
    $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);
}else {
  $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
}
```

> if attempt successfully then add this line in the attempt method

`$this->clearLoginAttempts($request);`

> else fail login then add this
> line in else condition

`$this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);`

Answer (score 5):

open you login controller

```
App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php
```

and paste it

```
protected $maxAttempts = 1;
protected $decayMinutes = 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

For Laravel 8 Developers you don't need to provide a trait or any thing because it is a build-in feature all you have to do is to put the middle ware chaining with the route you want to protect with limit rates like **below**

```
Route::post("/user/login",[LoginController::class,'login'])->middleware("throttle:10,2");
```

as same as @Jignesh Joisar explanation

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `ThrottlesLogins` trait in your controller and then you can controll it via properies `maxAttempts` / `decayMinutes`

```php
....
class TagController extends Controller
{
  use ThrottlesLogins;

  protected $maxAttempts = 5;
  protected $decayMinutes = 1;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Open App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController.php and add these lines:

```
protected $maxLoginAttempts = 10; 
protected $lockoutTime = 120;
```