# Laravel Sanctum Login Throttle api

Tags: laravel, api, authentication, mobile, throttling

How can I limit the number of request to login route if identifiant not match ?
I send a axios request to my external API Laravel

```
Route::post('/login', function (Request $request) {
$request->validate([
    'email' => 'required|email',
    'password' => 'required|string',
    'device_name' => 'required',
]);



$user = App\Models\User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

if (! $user || ! Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
    throw ValidationException::withMessages([
        'email' => ['The provided credentials are incorrect.'],
    ]);
}


return $user->createToken($request->device_name)->plainTextToken;
```

});

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52672416/limit-login-attempts-in-laravel-5-7

Comment: Trait ThrottlesLogins not work with Sanctum I think